# Access to the path 'path-name' is denied (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, path

I get error:

```
Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/MobileSell/backup/fromserver' is denied
```

When I'm trying to save zip file in `fromserver` folder like that:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath, basedataZipFile);
```

The values of the variables I'm passing to WriteAllBytes method are:

```
GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString() + "/MobileSell/backup/fromserver";
byte[] basedataZipFile = resultFromService[0];
```

I have the permissions set in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This has always worked but it started giving error 30 minutes ago.Do you know what may be the cause? Here is a screenshot how `fromserver` folder looks like on screen:

[image]

Comment: Please check whether the folder exists on the device you tested. If the folder does exists, please try clear the app and re-deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In method:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath, basedataZipFile);
```

A part from specifying the path where I want to save the `zip` I have to specify the `zip` file name also. So it looks like that:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(GlobalVariables.fromserverFolderPath + "/" + basedataZipName, basedataZipFile);
```

And it works. The strange thing is that I didn't have to specify the name of the zip file before and it worked. Anyway...